# what is the purpose of mov %rax,%rax?

Tags: gcc, assembly

I am currently learning ASM by disassembling some of C codes. One thing interested me is that the gcc compiler generates code like this

```
movq %rax,%rax
```

which is obviously meaningless. So what is the purpose of doing that?

I am wondering if it is used for waste a few cycles of CPU in order to improve the pipeline?

Thank you for your hint!

Comment: It's not used to improve pipeline. All x86 processors (for historical reasons?) have hardware that solves such hazards by stalling when neccessary. Only RISCs, that are simplier, need compiler support for that.

Comment: @ruslik: a stall is itself a hazard.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is basically a no-op, yes.

The compiler does this because branching to an address aligned on a 4-byte boundary is faster than branching to an unaligned address. So if you have a loop, the compiler will insert "padding" just before the start of it in order to get it into alignment.

Comment: Looks like a reasonable explanation. But why not use NOP instruction?

Comment: x86 doesn't have a "dedicated" nop instruction. The 1-byte NOP instruction has the exact opcode as `xchg %eax,%eax`, and similarly for other nop sizes. The compiler chooses a no-op with the right size for the amount of padding it needs.

Comment: Because a standard NOP instruction is 1 byte long, and the compiler needed 2 bytes for padding. 1 instruction is faster than 2, even if both are NOPs. For ex, the common 3 bytes NOP is `lea edi, [edi + 0]`

Comment: Actually, opcode 0x90 (corresponding to `xchg %eax, %eax` in 32-bit code) *is* a dedicated NOP on x86-64. If you do this with any other 32-bit register, it will clear the top 32 bits of the corresponding 64-bit register, but not in the "eax, eax" form.